# Texshop incorrectly states that a figure reference is multiply defined

Tags: labels, texshop

in TexShop the log file shows the warning

```
label 'fig:InfExp' multiply defined
```

but in my .tex file this label appears exactly 3 times-- twice in  \cite commands and, between these, once as a label definition in a figure environment.

when I retired from my Professor's job in 2001 I was fluent in latex. But I am now writing another paper. It's gone well  up to now and I am close to done, TexShop won't typeset til I clear this warning this is my 4th day trying to fix it

Comment: First it to figure out if this is a TeXShop issue: can you try building the tex file using a separate tex installation? For example, get a free account on [Overleaf](https://overleaf.com) and upload your source files there and see whether it also makes a complaint?

Comment: texshop is just the editor you are using so isn't really involved in the error, the error comes from latex, note that it doesn't mean the \label appears twice in the source just that it is executed twice, inputting the same file twice would produce that warning for example. It should be easy for you to make a small example, start from a copy of your document and delete everything that you can while still showing the error. do you really have `fig:InfExp` in a `\cite` ??

Comment: You are using the label as a bibliography citation and as a label for cross referencing.